How do I make the lines thinner in Python?
In the process of obtaining PPTX using Python, I faced the problem of having to thin the thickness of the lines.
How can I solve this?
I tried to use python-pptx library to implement it.
I'd be happy if you could take a look and let me know your feedback.

what lines exactly?

That sounds very interesting.
I previously solved this problem with the following solution.
In python-pptx, all shapes have line and stroke properties.
You will need to access this property to proceed with setup.
I will share a simple sample code.
line_style = shape1.line
line_style.width = Pt(0.25)

You can test this code.

I dont need existing shape code, I need that the lines of new box must be made thin.

I see.
If you want that the lines of new box must be made thin, you can use this code snap.
shape = slide.shapes.add_shape(MSO_SHAPE.ROUNDED_RECTANGLE, 0, 0, Pt(shape_width), Pt(shape_height))
line_style = shape.line
line_style.width = Pt(0.25)

I could not understand your question exactly, but as I understood it:
    from pptx import Presentation
    from pptx.enum.shapes import MSO_SHAPE_TYPE
    
    # Load the PowerPoint presentation
    pptx_path = "your_presentation.pptx"
    prs = Presentation(pptx_path)
    
    # Iterate through each slide in the presentation
    for slide in prs.slides:
        # Iterate through each shape in the slide
        for shape in slide.shapes:
            # Check if the shape is a line shape
            if shape.shape_type == MSO_SHAPE_TYPE.LINE:
                # Thin the line by setting its width
                shape.line.width = 0.75  # Adjust the value as needed (in points)
    
    # Save the modified presentation
    modified_pptx_path = "modified_presentation.pptx"
    prs.save(modified_pptx_path)


